# I opened .vcf contact file in my pc and it keeps showing me all the contacts, I'm not able to close?

Tags: vcf-vcard

Basically, I inserted my sd card on my PC (Windows), and I've a contact file (.vcf) that contains around 1000 contact, once I clicked on this file, the first contact is opened, once I close that contact, the next one pup, like endless loop, how to stop this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this belongs on stack overflow, try asking your question on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Can't vote for closing due to bounty. Woot?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this might be to utilize the Task Manager and kill the process. Press Ctrl + Shift + Esc to open Task Manager, and go to Processes. Find the wab.exe process and end it.

And of course you could try restarting your Windows system.

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

try opening it in your spreadsheet program (or anything else) it. Just Right Click and OPEN WITH.